# Dynamic adding of columns in R

Tags: r

I need some help with finding a good way to dynamically add columns with counts for different categories that I need to extract from a string.

In my data, I have a column that contains names of categories and counts thereof. The fields can be empty or contain any combination of categories one can think of. Here are some examples:

```
themes:firstcategory_1;secondcategory_33;thirdcategory_5
themes:secondcategory_33;fourthcategory_2
themes:fifthcategory_1
```

What I need is a column for each category (should have the category's name) and the count extracted from the strings above. The list of categories is dynamic, so I don't know beforehand which ones exist.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Please include your desired output as a table, so we can get a better idea of what you are looking for. Also include any code that you have tried to attempt to solve this and where it has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will get a column for each category with the counts for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# Create test dataframe
df <- data.frame(themes = c("firstcategory_1;secondcategory_33;thirdcategory_5", "secondcategory_33;fourthcategory_2","fifthcategory_1"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get the number of columns to split values into
cols <- max(str_count(df$themes,";")) + 1

# Get vector of temporary column names
cols <- paste0("col",c(1:cols))

df <- df %>%
      # Add an ID column based on row number
      mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
      # Separate multiple categories by semicolon
      separate(col = themes, into = cols, sep = ";", fill = "right") %>%
      # Gather categories into a single column
      gather_("Column", "Value", cols) %>%
      # Drop temporary column
      select(-Column) %>%
      # Filter out NA values
      filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
      # Separate categories from their counts by underscore
      separate(col = Value, into = c("Category","Count"), sep = "_", fill = "right") %>%
      # Spread categories to create a column for each category, with the count for each ID in that category
      spread(Category, Count)
```